# HoltWinters forecast in R

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, holtwinters

I have a [time series](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c9818oa7b2qzmn/ID.csv?dl=0) divided in 30 days and hour , so 720 values (24h*30).

[image]

Every Saturday and  Sunday as you can see I have the lowest values at the time series . (It starts from friday).

I divided the time series in 3 week for "train" and 1 for test with the 4th.
I applied HoltWinters method at first 3 week and then I did a forecast on 4th week and make a comparison beetween observed value and simulated.

```
Test<-function(ID,Unique,i){
  DfIn<-ID$V4[1:552]
  DfReal<-ID$V4[553:720]
  x<-ts(data=DfIn,frequency=24)
  HW<-HoltWinters(x,beta = FALSE)
  Pred<-forecast.HoltWinters(HW,168)
  print("Accuracy")
  print(accuracy(Pred,DfReal))
  Box1<-Box.test(Pred$residuals,type="Ljung-Box")
  P<-Box1$p.value
  return (P)
}
```

This is the comparison [image]
where **Blue line are simulated value and Red line are observed value.**

The problem is , why simulated value don't follow the red line when timeseries got the lowest value on saturday and sunday? Is there a way to get more accuracy and let prediction to be more similar to observed?

Update:

[image]

Comment: More of a stats question than programming

Comment: Wow, it looks so good mape is less than first. I post the result on main post.

Comment: Anyone care to post an official answer if this answers the question?

Comment: @lukeA just one thing, in this way p-value goes from ~0.059 to 0.2430634.

Does it influence the significance of the model?

Comment: Also I got this Warn 

`In HoltWinters(x, beta = FALSE) : optimization difficulties: ERROR: ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH`

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning. What "significance of the model" do you mean?

Comment: From box.test I p-value like ~0.2430 when before it was ~0.059 . 
It should be <= 0.05 right?

Comment: No it should be greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try

```
x<-ts(data=DfIn,frequency=7*24)
```